# Select multiple checkboxes onclick for delete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, checkbox, react-redux

I have a set of checkboxes to display, my need is to create a delete button which will be used for selecting multiple check boxes to delete.
From 'Select boxes to delete' it'll change to 'Delete' on onClick event, at that time we'll get options to select multiple checkboxes after selecting clicking on delete it should be delete.

Can anyone give me idea on this , to select multiple checkboxes to delete from list.

THanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the checked value along with your data in state. Once it is checked the state will be modified and accordingly delete will work.

Refer [this](https://j2dqy.csb.app/) demo I tried.

Comment: Thanks, it seems working good, can i get code referrence. ItemList and Product js you have written

Comment: Thank you, and if we have to delete those selected one from api means how we can do that?